# Spark job failed due to permission issue on directory level

Tags: linux, apache-spark

I created a spark Application in scala. I called the spark submit command from a shell script

my spark application is reading  files from a HDFS input directory .

I run the spark job with user as build. My spark job is trying to read and process all files from /data/published/source/oogway/tracking_id_log/TRACKING_ID_LOG_FULL

/data/published/source/omega/omega_tracking_log/OMEGA_LOG_FULL is a directory created by  a user metro

metro and build are in same group named hadoop

I can clearly see that build user is having read access to that HDFS directory , then Why do I get below error?

```
 Exception in thread "main"  org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied:  user=build, access=READ_EXECUTE,\
    inode="/data/published/source/omega/omega_tracking_log/OMEGA_LOG_FULL":metro:hadoop:drwxr-----
            at  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.checkFsPermission(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:257)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.check(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:238)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.checkPermission(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:151)
            at org.apache.sentry.hdfs.SentryAuthorizationProvider.checkPermission(SentryAuthorizationProvider.java:174)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:138)
```

Here is the access for that HDFS directory

```
bash-4.1$ hdfs dfs -ls /data/published/source/omega/omega_tracking_log
Found 3 items

 drwxr-----   - metro hadoop          0 2017-06-12 13:12 /data/published/source/omega/omega_tracking_log/OMEGA_LOG_FULL
```

If spark wants to read all files from a HDFS directory and to process it then Do we need to have EXECUTE access on HDFS directory  for the spark user as well?

Comment: HDFS works exactly like a Linux filesystem: READ privilege on  directory simply enables you to read its *name*. To *browse the contents* you need EXECUTE privilege.

Comment: @Samson: So Does it mean that if a spark application is reading all files from HDFS directory then we should have EXECUTE access to that HDFS directory and READ access to all files in that HDFS directory?

Comment: Yes, `r` and `x` on the directory, and `r` on the files inside. Just run a test!

Comment: Thank you very much .It worked

Answer (score -2):

This issues is because of permission of HDFS. Can you try this

1. login from root user
   change the permission of HDFS

   hadoop fs -chmod -R 777 /
2. And try to run spark job

Comment: So your solution to a specific and local authorization issue is to **suppress** all authorizations globally?!? Tell that to regulated companies that must set fine-grained authorization (with ACLs) and an audit log for data access...